# sound card in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, sound-card

How can I see hardware information for my sound card in Linux?

Comment: The "hardware information" phrase is a bit ambiguous. If you will specify it more precisely you will probably get better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [**`lsusb`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsusb) - Display information about USB buses in the system and the devices connected to them.

or

> [**`lspci`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lspci) - Display information about PCI buses in the system and devices connected to them.

Answer (score 0):

`aplay -L`
or -h as there are a lot of options

Comment: No need for `sudo` on Ubuntu, just checked that on fresh 10.04 install. It's better not to use `sudo` when you're not required to do it just because it lowers your chances to accidentally run something destructive.

Comment: @whitequark - True, I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec*
```

Comment: cat: /proc/asound/card0/codec97#0: Is a directory

Comment: Oh now that's interesting.  Usually it's a text file with a full codec dump for the device. So what files are in the directory?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/L9Pwnfue

Comment: ok then, try /proc/asound/card0/codec97#0/ac97#0-0